# Introduce momentary delays in ember-cli-mirage

Tags: ember.js, ember-testing, ember-cli-mirage

I am using ember-cli-mirage for acceptance tests. For a specific case, I would like to check the behaviour while fetching data over a slow connection.

There's a setting in ember-cli-mirage called `timing` that simulates a delay in the response. However, this setting cannot be changed to be different in a specific test:

```
// app/mirage/config.js
this.timing = 400;
```

Something else I have tried is returning a promise at the fake endpoint. Through some import/export, I could control the resolution of the promise from my test. Unfortunately, ember-cli-mirage doesn't seem to recognise the return value as a promise, and simply passes it back to the adapter verbatim:

```
// app/mirage/config.js
this.get('/StopPoint/Search/:term', (db, request) => {
  return freezer.run(function() {
    return db[`stop-point-search-${request.params.term}`][0];
  });
});

// At my test
freezer.on()
runTests()
freezer.off()
```

**The question**: is there any way to do this? Ie: to control the delay of a specific response in ember-cli-mirage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few thoughts:

- You can change timing within a specific test via `server.timing`. The server should be reinstantiated for each test so this wouldn't affect other tests.

  ```
  test('for slow behavior', function() {
    server.timing = 400;
    //
  });
  ```
- You can also redefine route handlers within tests as shown here in [the second example of the Acceptance testing guides](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.1.x/acceptance-testing/#asserting-a-server-call-was-made-in-a-test). If you're using `0.2.0-beta`, route handlers have a `timing` option you can use to affect just that handler:

  ```
  test('for slow behavior', function() {
    server.get('/slow-query', (schema, request) => {
      //
      return data;
    }, {timing: 400};

    visit('/');
    //
    assert();
  });
  ```

I think your instinct to return something you have control over freezing would be the ideal way to test this, in tandem with something like [Timecop](https://github.com/jamesarosen/Timecop.js). Perhaps Mirage can add an API for this eventually.

Comment: Hmm, it works, but I'm not sure if it's actually useful. Due to the way the run loop is wired up, I can't get to test what's going on in that interim period while the app is waiting for the response :-/ Of course my understanding of the run loop is lacking, so I might be missing something?

Comment: What code in your app is making the network request? Model hook on route handler?

Comment: No, it's in a controller. It's a search query and the search term is mapped from a query argument.

Comment: @SamSelikoff, I tried to simulate a network throttling in the testing environment but I can't do that becoz of the async helpers.
Steps:
1) set server timing in ec-mirage to 1000ms
2) triggered an action
3) again set server timing in ec-mirage to 0ms
4) triggered the same action
5) used `async wait()`

practically, the second call should resolve first. But it was not since the later server timing override the configuration. Anyway, I can test this case?
That was not the model hook!

Answer (score 0):

We had to test that our `<progress>` element displays in a test using mirage and discovered that making the [`render`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-test-helpers/blob/master/API.md#render) method syncronous and piggybacking off of [`waitFor`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-test-helpers/blob/master/API.md#waitfor) and [`settled`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-test-helpers/blob/master/API.md#settled) works best (and doesn't require setting `this.server.timing` at all):

```js
const SELECTORS = {
    LOADING_SPINNER: '[role="progressbar"]'
};

test('it displays loading spinner when fetching blog post', async function(assert) {
    this.blogId = 1;
    render(hbs`<BlogPost @blogId={{this.blogId}}/>`); // NOTE: no await
    await waitFor(SELECTORS.LOADING_SPINNER);
    assert.dom(SELECTORS.LOADING_SPINNER).exists({ count: 1 }, 'loading spinner rendered while blog post loads');
    await settled();
    assert.dom(SELECTORS.LOADING_SPINNER).doesNotExist('loading spinner removed when blog post loaded');
});
```